# Select correct bound button using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 buttons in a table row. A "start" button and a "complete" button. Right now I'm using this code to run an AJAX call.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on("click", "button", function(){
        rowID = "row" + this.id;
        $("#" + rowID).load("eventHandlersPHP/updateStart.php", {
            roomID: this.id
        });
    });

    $(document).on("click", "button", function(){
        rowID = "row" + this.id;
        $("#" + rowID).load("eventHandlersPHP/updateComplete.php", {
            roomID: this.id
        });
    });

});
```

Right now my code doesn't know which button to grab and just randomly picks which code to run.
How do I only select the first button or second button in that row and still have it be bound.

Comment: Get rid of one of the event bindings, and add conditional logic to check what `this.id` is. If it's your start button, call the first URL, if it's the complete, then call the other. If your ID is not indicative of which button was clicked, consider using a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). I'd also suggest including your HTML markup so that this is a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense but how would I select if this.id starts with "S" or if this.id starts with "C".

Comment: You can use data-id attribute to store the id button. Then get it when click like $(this).attr('data-id')...Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**change your selector :**

```
$('button:nth-child(1)').click(function(){
...
})
$('button:nth-child(2)').click(function(){
...
})
```

**or user javascript to call click event on html code:**

in HTML:

```
<button onclick="fun1()">btn1</button>
```

in javascript:

```
function fun1(){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a conditional to check the text of the button  and use that to select which template to load. This will also allow you to combine your two functions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on("click", "button", function(){
        rowID = "row" + this.id;
        if ($(this).text() == "start"){
          $("#" + rowID).load("eventHandlersPHP/updateStart.php", {
              roomID: this.id     
          });
         }else {
           $("#" + rowID).load("eventHandlersPHP/updateComplete.php", {
            roomID: this.id
           });
          }
});
```